# How to get PID when start bash script

Tags: scripting, process, pv

I'm running bash files for zfs send jobs and this my bash file example:

```
zfs send -Rc tank/test@snap | pv -fs datasize -F "%p***%t***%e***%r***%b" |
  mbuffer -q -s 128k -m 1G -O ip:port
```

When I start the bash I want to know PV pid. 
I couldn't figure out how can I take pv pid.

Comment: use the command `pgrep pv`

Comment: I have more than one pv process. Thats why I want to take when i started.

Comment: ps -eaf | grep -i scriptname| awk '{print $2}|head -1

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS Its only gives me my bash pid. I want to take PV pid.
My script as you can see creates 4 different pid in same time. 1=bash pid, 2=zfs pid, 3=pv pid, 4=mbuffer pid. I need to catch PV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe viewer has an option for this job.
You can save pid to a file with this command.

-P FILE, --pidfile FILE
Save the process ID of pv in FILE. The file will be truncated if it already exists, and will be removed when pv exits. While pv is running, it will contain a single number - the process ID of pv - followed by a newline.